# Node.js EventEmitter error

Tags: node.js, restify, eventemitter

I have an error when trying to inherit EvenEmitter

```
/* Consumer.js */
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var util = require('util');

var Consumer = function() {};

Consumer.prototype = {
  // ... functions ...
  findById: function(id) {
    this.emit('done', this);
  }
};

util.inherits(Consumer, EventEmitter);
module.exports = Consumer;

/* index.js */
var consumer = new Consumer();
consumer.on('done', function(result) {
  console.log(result);
}).findById("50ac3d1281abba5454000001");

/* ERROR CODE */
{"code":"InternalError","message":"Object [object Object] has no method 'findById'"}
```

I've tried almost everything and still dont work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things. You are overwriting the prototype rather than extending it. Also, move the util.inherits() call before you add the new method:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var util = require('util');

var Consumer = function Consumer() {}

util.inherits(Consumer, EventEmitter);

Consumer.prototype.findById = function(id) {
    this.emit('done', this);
    console.log('found');
};

var c = new Consumer();
c.on('done', function(result) {
  console.log(result);
});

c.findById("50ac3d1281abba5454000001");
```

Comment: i just notice the inherit problem, why did you leave the c.findById appart?

Comment: Just for readability, it was trying to make sure I understood your code.

Comment: also, why Consumer.prototype = {} wont work but Consumer.prototype.function yes

Comment: Because when you do "Consumer.prototype = {}" you are **overwriting** the prototype rater than adding a new property/function to it.